# How do I toggle off some specified series by default in HighChart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

As the arrows say in the picture, I want to hide the two series at first. But the user can toggle it on by clicking it.

What should I do?

I made a guess and tried this (to add `disabled:true` to the settings) but not working:

```
series: [{
        name: 'PV',
        data: pv_arr,yAxis:0,disabled:true
    },
    {
      name:'UPV',
      data:upv_arr,yAxis:0
    },
    {
      name:'PPV',
      data:ppv_arr,yAxis:1,disabled:true
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`visible` option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible):

```
{
    name: 'PV',
    data: pv_arr,
    yAxis: 0,
    visible: false
}
```